# Vue with VCalendar component: Keep data in sync with another Vue instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm programming a page that displays a list of meetings in a table. It's also possible to edit and delete meetings. Now I'd like to offer an alternative view using [VCalendar](https://vcalendar.io/).

Data is received from the server on page load and stored in a JS variable. Both the Vue instance containing the table and the VCalendar component share this data. If I edit a table cell, the changes are reflected in the component. *But when I delete a date in the table view, it remains in the calendar.*

This is the relevant HTML (edit: Added some attributes to the `td`):

```
<calendar-component></calendar-component>

<table id='meetings-table'>
    <tr v-for='meeting in meetings' :key='date.id'>
        <td contenteditable @blur='handleInput($event,meeting,"name")>
            @{{ meeting.name }}
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox' v-model='selected'
                   :value='meeting.id'>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div>
    <button v-if='selected.length' @click='deleteMeetings'>
        Delete selected rows
    </button>
</div>
```

My JS (edit: Added `handleInput` method):

```
let table = new Vue({
    el:'#meetings-table',
    data: {
        selected:      [],
        meetings:  window.meetings,
    },
    methods: {
        /**
         * Deletes selected meetings.
         */
        deleteMeetings: function () {
            let requests = [];

            // Make a single request and store it
            for (let id of this.selected) {
                requests.push(axios.delete('/termine/' + id)
                    .then(response => {
                        // Remove meetings
                        this.meetings = this.meetings.filter(t => t.id != id);
                        // Remove id from list of selected meetings
                        this.selected = this.selected.filter(elem => elem != id);
                    }));
            }

            const axiosArray = axios.all(requests);
        },
        /**
        * Handles edits in table cells.
        */
        handleInput: function($event, meeting, field) {
            const newValue = $event.target.textContent;

            // Update value in $data
            meeting[field] = newValue;

            // AJAX request follows, but is not necessary for this example to work
        }

    }
});
```

The relevant parts of the component:

```
<template>
  <v-calendar :attributes='attributes'>

    <div
      slot='meeting-row'
      slot-scope='{ customData }'>
      <!-- Popover content omitted -->
    </div>

  </v-calendar>
</template>

<script>

let meetings = window.meetings;

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      incId: meetings.length,
      editId: 0,
      meetings,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    attributes() {
      return [
        // Today attribute
        {
          // ...
        },
        // Meeting attributes
        ...this.meetings.map(meeting => ({
          key: meeting.id,
          dates: new Date('2018,11,31'),// moment(meeting.slot.date, 'DD.MM.YY').format('YYYY, MM, DD'), //meeting.dates,
          customData: meeting,
          order: meeting.id,
          dot: {
            backgroundColor: '#ff8080',
          },
          popover: {
            // Matches slot from above
            slot: 'meeting-row',
          }
        }))
      ];
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This is what happens:

- I load the page containing only a single meeting. The meeting is
  shown both in the table and the calendar component. Vue devtools show
  it in both `meetings` arrays (in the component as well as in the other
  Vue instance). Using the console, I can also see it in
  `window.meetings`.
- After clicking the delete button (triggering the `deleteMeetings` method in my JS), the meeting is gone from the table, but remains in
  the calendar, in the component's `meetings` array and in
  `window.meetings`.

What do I have to change to keep the `meetings` arrays in sync even when *deleting* a meeting in the table? Note that I haven't yet implemented any methods for the calendar component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calendar, and table components should share a single state: currently selected meetings. From what I understand, right now you have that state in 2 separate places: `table` Vue instance, and a `calendar-component`, which is a child of some other Vue instance.

It may look like you're sharing the state already (with `window.meetings`), but it's not the case: you only initialize the same set of meetings when the components are created. And then changes in one component are not reflected in another component.

What you can try to do is to have meetings stored in the 'main' Vue app on your page, pass them as props to table and calendar components, and then trigger events from table and calendar components, when meetings array is modified. You should also define the event hanlders in the 'main' Vue app, and listen on components. A rough sketch of the solution:

```
<div id="app">
    <table-component
        :meetings="meetings" 
        @meetingUpdated="handleMeetingUpdate" 
        @meetingDeleted="handleMeetingDeletion"
    ></table-component>
    <calendar-component 
        :meetings="meetings" 
        @meetingUpdate="handleMeetingUpdate" 
        @meetingDeleted="handleMeetingDeletion"
    ></calendar-component>
</div>

let app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data: {
        meetings: []
    },
    methods: {
        handleMeetingUpdate(event) {
            //
        },
        handleMeetingDeletion(event) {
            //
        },
    }
    //
});
```

I hope the above is enough to point you in the right direction. If not, please let me know, and I'll do my best to help you with this further.

Comment: Thanks, I'll think about that. The strange thing is that edits *are* reflected in the other component. In my original code, the `td` containing `meeting.name` is `contenteditable`, and after an edit I just need to update that piece in the instance's data property (`meeting.name = 
John Doe`), which is reflected in the calendar.

Comment: I'm not sure about how the edit works, since you haven't posted that part. But in `deletePersons` method, you're specifically deleting meetings in `table` Vue instance, and not in thw window object (you mentionened that it's not being updated). So computed property `attributes` in calendar component has no way to pick up on that. I'm not sure if it could if you modify the window object. I am also not sure why you want to manage the `meetings` state outside of a Vue app (i.e. why you're doing it in the window object).

Comment: I added a bit of code in the first and second samples to show how editing works. I don't need to manage the meetings state outside of Vue, this is just how my code evolved: I already had `window.meetings` before I came up with the calendar idea to store all meetings on page load without an additional AJAX request.

Comment: Regarding the ajax part in `handleInput`: when you comment it out, the changes in meeting name done in the table are reflected in the calendar, right?
But still, I'd suggest to keep the meetings state in the main Vue instance, and pass them as a prop to table, and calendar components. This way you're sure about how the changes flow between components, and the instance keeping the global state. Getting the window object involved, you may be getting away from triggering events from components, but you're loosing sight of the data flow.

Comment: Thanks again, I changed the code according to your suggestions and everything is working now. Using two components and keeping the data in a central Vue instance, it will also be much easier to implement the features that are still missing (update and edit in the calendar component).